Database design for related data with different properties
Let's say a manager wants to see the activities of their team members (similar to an audit log). From the client, activities are displayed in a single list.
Here are some types of activities:

Common fields

DateCreated


TaskActivity

TaskId
TaskType (i.e. add task, update task, delete task)


AwardActivity

AwardType (i.e. Leadership award, Communication award)
ReceiverId
SenderId
Comment


CourseActivity

CourseId
CourseActivityType (i.e. enroll, complete)



Expect that more types of activities may be added in the future.
Instincts are telling me that storing all this information in a single table is poor design. How would you approach modeling this use case?
Also, how should this data be sent via an API request? Should it all be in one list? Or should there be multiple API requests for different activity types?
I'm using EF Core (code first).
edit: I clarified some of the properties of the different types of activities

"Also, how should this data be sent via an API request? Should it all be in one list? Or should there be multiple API requests for different activity types?" -- This additional paragraph makes your question too broad.  As it stands, this question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.     So please remove this paragraph from the question, and ask it as a separate question.


Instincts are telling me that storing all this information in a single table is poor design. How would you approach modeling this use case?

This type of data structure exactly matches an object-relational database model.
Which is precisely what Entity Framework does.
You have already stated that you are using Entity Framework Core, (which makes me wonder why are you even posting this question,) and that you are doing code first. In this case, the table or tables is not really your concern. Your only concern is your class hierarchy.
So, create a class hierarchy with a base "Activity" class containing the common properties, and three derived classes for "TaskActivity", "AwardActivity", and "CourseActivity" each adding its own properties.
Store instances of such classes in a relational database using Entity Framework.
Entity Framework will choose either a:

"Table-per-hierarchy (and discriminator)" inheritance mapping strategy, which means that it will create only one table, or a

"Table-per-type" inheritance mapping strategy, which means that it will create four tables.


But you don't really care.
You can read all about that in Microsoft Learn / .NET / Entity Framework / Entity Framework Core / Inheritance.

I recommend Non-SQL database.
If you have to use SQL, try to model the activities with a tuple of field name, old value, new value and etc.
Such a table could blow up over time, better to talk to your manager to set a limit and archive the activities periodically.

I clarified some of the properties of the activities. Yes, this should be in an SQL database. Currently, I don't need to store old and new values. It's more like a notification when something relevant happens (i.e. a team member receiving an award, a team member enrolling in a course)

Essentially, you have two options for organizing your database schema:
Option 1: One table for activities.
CREATE TABLE activity_types
(
    type_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
    name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE activities
(
    id         UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    type_id    SMALLINT  NOT NULL REFERENCES activity_types (type_id),
    created    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    properties JSON      NOT NULL
);

The advantages of this approach include the lack of need to change the scheme when adding new types of activities.
Option 2: Separate tables for each type of activity.
CREATE TABLE task_types
(
    type_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE task_activities
(
    id           UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    task_type_id SMALLINT NOT NULL REFERENCES task_types (type_id),
    task_id      UUID     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
    id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TYPE course_activity AS ENUM ('enroll', 'complete');

CREATE TABLE course_activities
(
    id                   UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    course_activity_type course_activity NOT NULL,
    course_id            SMALLINT        NOT NULL REFERENCES courses (id)
);

/* and so on */

The main benefit of this approach is data integrity at the database level, but when adding a new activity type, you will need to make changes to the database schema.

Without additional conditions for your scenario of data output in one list, both options will work, regardless of the method of obtaining data from the database.
